# Why loops show low iteration rate when iterations are minimum

Tags: vb.net, loops

While doing some experiments with  Do `Until .. Loop` i had noticed that the **rate of iterations are varying according to the no.of iterations.** Consider the following code and calculations:

```
Dim tim As Double
Dim i As Integer = 0
tim = Now.Millisecond
Do Until i > 500
ListBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString)
i = i + 1
Loop
MsgBox(Now.Millisecond - tim)
```

The count, time taken to execute and rates are discussed below:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║     Count       Time Taken(Ms)        Rate(iterations/Ms)                       ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║       2             1                      0.5                                  ║
║       10            2                      0.2                                  ║
║       25            3                      0.12                                 ║
║       50            7                      0.14                                 ║
║      100           18                      0.18                                 ║
║      250           46                      0.184                                ║
║      500           82                      0.164                                ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Does any one have any idea about this variation in timing?

- what are the factors affecting the iteration rate?

Comment: The iteration rate seems to be constant for me

Answer (score 4):

One millisecond does not provide sufficient temporal resolution to profile your code given that processors work on the nanosecond scale. Furthemore `DateTime.Now.Milliseconds` is not actually accurate to 1 millisecond, you should use `Stopwatch` if you want that kind of precision.

Finally, using small list sizes isn't going to be representative of throughput because you're not considering time taken to JIT-optimize and also how all threads block when garbage-collection is performed.

Not to discourage you, but I recommend you read up on the principles of software profiling so you understand how to measure code's performance accurately.

Answer (score 3):

Seems linear to me. I plotted your times on the y-axis vs your loop iterations on the x-axis and it came out reasonably linearly as I expected. An R^2 value of 0.996 is pretty good. So according to this trendline you have about 0.352 seconds of overhead regardless of the number of iterations and then a climb of 0.167 seconds per iteration. Obviously these numbers aren't perfect but they do demonstrate an initial overhead and then a steady climb as opposed to the variation you think you are seeing.

[image: Chart Data]